# Chatting server using epoll - unexpected behavior

Tags: c, sockets, client-server, server, epoll

I'm working on writing a simple chatting server-client C program using epoll. I'm writing and testing it in Xubuntu, and I found something strange. Message from server to client is delivered well. But Message from client to server is delivered at the moment when I push enter key at 'SERVER SIDE(putty window)'
For example, if I type 'Hello World' in the client window and push enter key, the message doesn't show on the server side, however, when I push enter key on the server side, 'Hello World' shows on the window!
I think something is wrong in server.c but I can't find what's wrong. I used epoll and let it monitor EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT to receive and send messages.
In other hand, I wrote client program with multi-threading.
Full src are below without header.
Any comment will be appreciated. Thank you!

server.c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int serv_sock, clnt_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_adr, clnt_adr;
    socklen_t adr_sz;
    int str_len, i;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];

    struct epoll_event *ep_events;
    struct epoll_event event;
    int epfd, event_cnt;

    if(argc!=2) {
        printf("Usage : %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    serv_sock=socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&serv_adr, 0, sizeof(serv_adr));
    serv_adr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serv_adr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_adr.sin_port=htons(atoi(argv[1]));

    if(bind(serv_sock, (struct sockaddr*) &serv_adr, sizeof(serv_adr))==-1)
        error_handling("bind() error");
    if(listen(serv_sock, 5)==-1)
        error_handling("listen() error");

    epfd=epoll_create(EPOLL_SIZE);
    ep_events=malloc(sizeof(struct epoll_event)*EPOLL_SIZE);

    //set_nonblocking_mode(serv_sock);
    event.events=EPOLLIN;
    event.data.fd=serv_sock;    
    epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, serv_sock, &event);

    while(1) {
        event_cnt=epoll_wait(epfd, ep_events, EPOLL_SIZE, -1);
        if(event_cnt==-1) {
            puts("epoll_wait() error");
            break;
        }

        for(i=0; i<event_cnt; i++) {
            if(ep_events[i].data.fd==serv_sock) {
                adr_sz=sizeof(clnt_adr);
                clnt_sock = accept(serv_sock, (struct sockaddr*)&clnt_adr, &adr_sz);
                //set_nonblocking_mode(clnt_sock);
                event.events=EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT;
                event.data.fd=clnt_sock;
                epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, clnt_sock, &event);
                printf("connected client: %d \n", clnt_sock);
            }
            else {
                if((ep_events[i].events & EPOLLIN) == EPOLLIN) {
                    memset(buf, 0, BUF_SIZE);
                    str_len=read(ep_events[i].data.fd, buf, BUF_SIZE-1);
                    buf[str_len] = 0;
                    if(str_len==0) {    // close request!
                        epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, ep_events[i].data.fd, NULL);
                        close(ep_events[i].data.fd);
                        printf("closed client: %d \n", ep_events[i].data.fd);
                    }
                    /*
                    else if(str_len < 0) {
                        if(errno == EAGAIN)
                            break;
                    }*/
                    else {
                        fputs(buf, stdout);
                    }
                }

                if((ep_events[i].events & EPOLLOUT) == EPOLLOUT) {
                    fgets(buf, BUF_SIZE, stdin);
                    if(!strcmp(buf, "q\n") || !strcmp(buf, "Q\n")) {
                        epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, ep_events[i].data.fd, NULL);
                        close(ep_events[i].data.fd);
                        printf("closed client: %d \n", ep_events[i].data.fd);
                    }
                    else {
                        write(ep_events[i].data.fd, buf, strlen(buf));
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
    close(serv_sock);
    close(epfd);
    return 0;
}

void set_nonblocking_mode(int fd)
{
    int flag = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flag|O_NONBLOCK);
}

void error_handling(char *buf)
{
    fputs(buf, stderr);
    fputc('\n', stderr);
    exit(1);
}
```

client.c

```
void * send_msg(void * arg);
void * recv_msg(void * arg);
void error_handling(char * msg);

char name[NAME_SIZE]="[DEFAULT]";
char msg[BUF_SIZE];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    pthread_t snd_thread, rcv_thread;
    void * thread_return;
    if(argc!=4) {
        printf("Usage : %s <IP> <port> <name>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
     }

    sprintf(name, "[%s]", argv[3]);
    sock=socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(argv[1]);
    serv_addr.sin_port=htons(atoi(argv[2]));

    if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))==-1)
        error_handling("connect() error");

    pthread_create(&snd_thread, NULL, send_msg, (void*)&sock);
    pthread_create(&rcv_thread, NULL, recv_msg, (void*)&sock);
    pthread_join(snd_thread, &thread_return);
    pthread_join(rcv_thread, &thread_return);
    close(sock);  
    return 0;
}

void * send_msg(void * arg)   // send thread main
{
    int sock=*((int*)arg);
    char name_msg[NAME_SIZE+BUF_SIZE];
    while(1) 
    {
        fgets(msg, BUF_SIZE, stdin);
        if(!strcmp(msg,"q\n")||!strcmp(msg,"Q\n")) 
        {
            close(sock);
            exit(0);
        }
        sprintf(name_msg,"%s %s", name, msg);
        write(sock, name_msg, strlen(name_msg));
    }
    return NULL;
}

void * recv_msg(void * arg)   // read thread main
{
    int sock=*((int*)arg);
    char name_msg[NAME_SIZE+BUF_SIZE];
    int str_len;
    while(1)
    {
        str_len=read(sock, name_msg, NAME_SIZE+BUF_SIZE-1);
        if(str_len==-1) 
            return (void*)-1;
        name_msg[str_len]=0;
        fputs(name_msg, stdout);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void error_handling(char *msg)
{
    fputs(msg, stderr);
    fputc('\n', stderr);
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: While unrelated, your server will exhibit [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if `read` fails and returns `-1`. Hint: What do you think will happen if you use a negative index for an array?

Comment: As for your problem, try to step through the server line by line in a debugger, to see what *really* happens.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your server is blocked inside that fgets() call until you press return.  If you want your server to remain responsive, don't have it call fgets(stdin) unless you are certain their are bytes available to be read on stdin; or maybe just don't call fgets(stdin) at all.

Comment: As a hint to the comment by @JeremyFriesner you *do* know that as long as there is a single byte of buffer-space available for output, then the socket will be writable? Which means that unless you really saturate the output buffer of the socket, it will *always* be writable.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, but the issue in question here is whether or not stdin is readable, not whether a socket is writeable.  fgets() blocks until there is data available to *read* on stdin.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner What I meant, was that since a socket, by almost default, is writable, the first thing that happens in the server program once a connection is made is that the `epoll_wait` call will return saying that the socket is writable, and immediately go to that case where it gets stuck on the `fgets` call. My comment and the hint was directed to the OP.

Comment: Also (and directed to the OP), what I said in my last comment would have been *extremely* obvious after following the advice in my second comment (about stepping through the code in a debugger). Debuggers are your best and most important tool as a programmer, next to the compiler itself.

Comment: Thanks guys I'm studying it based on your comments!